# How to use "lorem" inside paragraph tag

Tags: emmet

I am just learning zen-coding and am trying to do this:

Entering 'lorem' and hitting tab will produce 50 word lorem text.

However, if I start with `<p></p>` and then type lorem + tab inside the tag, it does not produce the lorem text.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
p>lorem
```

and then `tab`

Answer (score 4):

Since people are still reading this I will add, if you want to print off many lorems inside of p tags you can do this:

```
(p>lorem)*7
```

Replace 7 with how many lines you want!

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<p>
lorem*(how many line you want)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 